Can I use decap CMS on Github pages without hosting the site on Netlify?
I am trying to setup my jekyll site, stored on GitHub, hosted on Github-pages with a Content Management System (CMS). Currently I have to create new markdown files and push to GitHub just to add a new post. I am trying to use DecapCMS but the instructions include netlify hosting specific steps, even though it's supposed to be independent of netlify.
Describe the bug
I followed the jekyll setup instructions and my site still can't use decap CMS.  I followed the instructions here
jekyll guide and here- GitHub backend to setup the GitHub backend.
I followed the steps to setup the identity widget
I have setup the secrets and got the client ID for my project but at the section that says to:

Follow the authentication provider setup steps in the Netlify docs

It says in the netlify docs

When you complete application registration with GitHub, you need to add the Client ID and Client Secret to your Netlify site:

Problem is that the site isn't hosted on Netlify, since it's on Github pages. I assumed I wouldn't have to change the hosting provider. But the remaining steps require a Netlify site to do these steps in the Netlify UI page. Clicking the links takes me to one of my other projects hosted on Netlify so I can enter the client ID and secret.

Go to Site configuration > Access & security > OAuth
Under Authentication Providers, select Install Provider.
Select GitHub and enter the Client ID and Client Secret from earlier, then save.

So this is where I had to stop following the tutorial on the DecapCMS docs. I feel I'm almost there but just missing something.
I tried to look for alternatives and found the section for external OAuth, but it doesn't have a jekyll setup with Github pages
[https://decapcms.org/docs/external-oauth-clients/](external OAuth)
Nevertheless I tried the serverless option and it just confused me more. If anyone knows how to use this I will be grateful for your help.
To Reproduce
Expected behavior
To be able to use Decap CMS on my Github pages website without changing hosting providers
Screenshots
This is what I see when I go to the /admin route.

Then it fails at this step

Applicable Versions:

Decap CMS version:
decap-cms-app 3.3.3
decap-cms.js:sourcemap:393 decap-cms-core 3.4.2
decap-cms.js:sourcemap:491 decap-cms 3.3.3
Git provider: GitHub
OS: Windows 11
Browser version Version 128.0.6613.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

CMS configuration
https://github.com/RDjarbeng/RDjarbeng/blob/main/admin/config.yml
Additional context
Site is my personal website located at:
https://rdjarbeng.github.io/RDjarbeng/
On GitHub:
https://github.com/RDjarbeng/RDjarbeng

Why don't I just use Netlify for everything?
The site settings are currently set to the options for Github-pages and I don't want to change that. On netlify the assets folder for some reason isn't setup correctly so the site displays without css and other media.
I don't want to change hosting platforms just for a CMS☹️
Similar post is on the decap-cms issue page:
https://github.com/decaporg/decap-cms/issues/7280

I think the crux is the authentication, from https://decapcms.org/docs/github-backend/ "Because GitHub requires a server for authentication, Netlify facilitates basic GitHub authentication." Netlify is that OAuth provider and I don't think GitHub Pages has one.

@mb21 yes, but it says on the DecapCMS site that the site does not have to be hosted on netlify and still use netlify for authentication or a different platform.  How to do that however was not specified in their tutorial

If you want to be able to use the CMS from your github pages domain at mysite/admin you'll have to setup your own authenticator client.
Currently it is not very clear how to do this in DecapCMS. An alternative is to use a similar CMS; Sveltia CMS which provides a quick way to migrate from DecapCMS and doesn't use Netlify Identify.
Once you've migrated to Sveltia CMS, it also has a sveltia authenticator you can use with Cloudflare to setup your authentication service. Find the steps here.
That was what worked for me to be able to use the CMS on my GitHub pages site without using Netlify. Authentication is done with GitHub.

Answer is misleading.
Not being able to setup alternative to example is completely different than "not possible". The need to spend some time to make it work is different than not being able to make it work.
this is duplicate of the same issue
https://github.com/decaporg/decap-website/issues/79#issuecomment-2388497883
but with wrong conclusions (personal conclusions presented as objective).
You can see in issue that other users have successfully set up authentication without netlify

This answer by @hip3r is not an answer and is actually a comment on a previous answer intended to criticize. This doesn't solve OP's problem.
The answer already specifies that setting up an authenticator outside Netlify is required & provides an alternative though best solution would still use DecapCMS.
Other users setup authentication without using Decap's steps -same as  answer- and for platforms other than gh-pages and jekyll as noted in the issue link.
No where - either issues page or on stackoverflow - is any solution said to be 'not possible'.
Solutions are welcome
